# OS X ~ vs Linux ~ in Tramp

Tags: tramp

I'm setting up a remote editing capability through Tramp from my Mac OS X laptop to an Ubuntu box, and have defined the following:

```
(setq tramp-default-user "myusername"
      tramp-default-host "myhostname")
(setq tramp-default-method "ssh")

;;Open a file on my linux box
(defun remote-find-file (file-name)
  "Like find file, but opens the file on my box"
  (interactive "FRemote Find File: ")
  (let ((tramp-file-name (expand-file-name file-name)))
    (find-file tramp-file-name)))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-u") 'remote-find-file)
```

The issue I have is that `expand-file-name` is expanded using the Mac OS X conventions, so that `~` turns into `/Users/myusername` instead of `/home/myusername`. I suspect there's a way to fix this using file name completion, but I can't figure it out from the Tramp documentation.

Comment: Do you need to `expand-file-name` at all? I think TRAMP works fine if you pass the name unexpanded.

Comment: I guess I should have thought of that. Duh. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`expand-file-name` doesn't use any convention, it asks your operating system what the home directory of the user is. It can't guess that you want the home directory of a user with the same name but on a different machine.

In any case, your function doesn't do anything useful as it stands. To open a file in your home directory on the remote machine, type

```
/myhostname:path/to/file
```

Put a slash after `/myhostname:` to give an absolute path on the remote host.

You can abbreviate `myhostname` by defining an alias in your SSH configuration ([example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11881/is-it-possible-to-use-one-ssh-key-per-account-for-each-account-on-a-given-remote/11883#11883)), so you'd have very little to type — with a one-letter alias, you'd just need to type `C-x C-f /r:` and then the file name to open a remote file. So I don't think the command you're trying to define is useful anyway.

Comment: Thanks, that's a much better solution. Now, can I also edit as superuser?

Comment: @rogerl Yes, but [it's more verbose](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177687/open-file-via-ssh-and-sudo-with-emacs): `/ssh:myhostname|sudo::/path/to/file` (but you can [define a shortcut for it](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/tramp/Multi_002dhops.html)).

Comment: Thanks. I had discovered the first syntax, but couldn't figure out from the documentation you pointed to how to actually set up a shortcut (I'm not really a LISP hacker). Would you mind putting an example in your answer?

Comment: @rogerl This is getting to deviate quite a lot from your original question, please post a new question.